# Problems rendering page with bootstrap menu in IE10

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-10

I've downloaded the bootrap package and I´ve created a standard menu offered by bootstrap. My page with this menu is shown ok in Firefox, Chrome, and IE10 if I execute `http://localhost/mypage_menu.htm`
But, if I execute `http://computer_name/mypage_menu.htm`, it only work ok in Firefox and Chrome.

I´m working, in both cases, in my computer.

Regards,
María

Comment: there is no way to debug this without being able to run the code. We don't have access to your localhost.

Comment: are there console errors?

Answer (score 2):

Me helped following element

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10"  />`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was caused by the IE security settings.  Open http://<**your_server**> in IE10, then open Internet Options-->Security-->Sites and add the server.  This resolved the problem for me.